# Вставить php код в ссылку

Tags: php, html

Добрый день! Я только начинаю изучать PHP самостоятельно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вставить php-код в ссылку?

```
<?
Cmodule::IncludeModule('citrus.tszh');
$arResult["ACCOUNTS"] = Array();
$dbAccounts = CTszhAccount::GetList($arOrder = array(), $arFilter = array("USER_ID"=>CUser::GetID()), $arGroupBy = false, $arNavStartParams = false, $arSelectFields = array("*"));
$arAccount = $dbAccounts->GetNext();
echo $arAccount["XML_ID"]; 
?>
```

Чтобы получилась ссылка вида `https://www.somesite.ru/pay/PERSONAL_ACCOUNT=###`, где `###` и есть этот PHP-код

Пробовала так:

```
<?
Cmodule::IncludeModule('citrus.tszh');
$arResult["ACCOUNTS"] = Array();
$dbAccounts = CTszhAccount::GetList($arOrder = array(), $arFilter = array("USER_ID"=>CUser::GetID()), $arGroupBy = false, $arNavStartParams = false, $arSelectFields = array("*"));
$arAccount = $dbAccounts->GetNext();
echo '<a href="https://www.somesite.ru/pay/PERSONAL_ACCOUNT='$arAccount["XML_ID"];'">Ссылка</a>'
?>
```

И, конечно же, ничего не получается. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: что означает 'вставить php код в ссылку?', просто код вы не можете вставить в ссылку, что вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: Есть подозрение что сначала вам стоит изучить основы веба в целом.

Comment: Я имела ввиду то, что мне нужно заменить ### на результат PHP-кода, приведенного выше

Comment: Для вывода нескольких строк - используйте конкатенацию: `echo '<a href="https://www.somesite.ru/pay/PERSONAL_ACCOUNT=' . $arAccount["XML_ID"] . '">Ссылка</a>'`

Comment: @u_mulder , Ооогромнейшее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Либо через конкатенацию

```
echo '<a href="https://www.somesite.ru/pay/PERSONAL_ACCOUNT='.$arAccount["XML_ID"].'">Ссылка</a>'
```

Либо либо через интерпретирование.

```
echo "<a href='https://www.somesite.ru/pay/PERSONAL_ACCOUNT={$arAccount["XML_ID"]}'>Ссылка</a>"
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php? ;)